What does scripture say regarding post humous diksha?
Recently I have come across the life story of Srila Bhakti Siddhanta Saraswati Maharaj from the Gaudiya Vaishnav Sampradaya. It was stated that in 1918, he accepted sanyas diksha from the photograph of his Guru Gaurkisora Dasa Babaji posthumously.
Are there any other such examples?
